# I want HTACCESS to block only direct access to a specific file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a file that I don't want users to be able to navigate to on their own accord. However, if they click a link that sends them there, it's okay for the page to work. I currently have my htaccess file set up like so.

```
<Files "success.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

`success.php` is the name of the file, and in the directory of the `success.php`, I have the following in a htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule /?\.htaccess$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/paypal/success\.php$ - [F,L]
```

Will users still be able to get to `success.php` if they're directed there, because I know you're shown a 403 error if you just try to navigate there.

If it is the case that they will be blocked from being directed there, is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: they will still be blocked. As its a php file, ditch the .htaccess and use some conditional logic, eg check a session var

Answer (score 0):

When I type a URL to "success.php" in my browser's location bar and hit enter, my browser sends a request for success.php.

When I go to your website and click on a link that takes me to "success.php", my browser sends a request for success.php.

It's exactly the same, just because I click on a link on your site vs typing it in my browser, both are requested exactly the same. So when you deny access, you deny all access. What you need to check for the is "Referer" header, which browsers can (optionally) include in a request to let the webserver know what URL it just came from. Referers can be easily forged or sometimes omitted, so checking the referer isn't a guarantee.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/paypal/success\.php$ - [F,L]
```

So if someone loads any page on the "example.com" site (e.g. your site) and then clicks on a link that goes to the success.php page, they'll be fine. Any other access from anywhere else will be 403.

Comment: I added this to the .htaccess, I still get a 403 when clicking on a href I made just to check if it works.